# Проблема в запуске бота Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

Ход моих действий при запуске бота таков:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
      executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
      event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      event_loop.run_until_complete(start_server())
      event_loop.run_forever()
```

Сперва я запускаю бота, после чего происходит создание веб [сокета](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)), в котором есть бесконечный цикл:

```py
async def new_client_connected(client_socket,path):
      print("New Client")
      while True:
        new_message = await client_socket.recv()
        print(new_message)
    
    async def start_server():
      print("Server Started")
      await websockets.serve(new_client_connected, "localhost",1234)
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

```
    INFO:aiogram:Bot: CHIMERA BOT [@TheChimera_bot]
    WARNING:aiogram:Updates were skipped successfully.
    INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling.
    INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Stop polling...
    WARNING:aiogram:Goodbye!
    C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\truebot.py:262: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
      
    Take it!
    ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 139, in make_request
        async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
      File "C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
        self._resp = await self._coro
      File "C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 560, in _request
        await resp.start(conn)
      File "C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 899, in start
        message, payload = await protocol.read()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
      File "C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 616, in read
        await self._waiter
    aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [Errno 1] [SSL: APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2672)
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
        updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
      File "C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
        result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
      File "C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
        return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
      File "C:\Users\babal\Desktop\telegramBot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 142, in make_request
        raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
    aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientOSError: [Errno 1] [SSL: APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2672)
    WARNING:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Polling is stopped.
```

Я предполагаю, что это из-за того, что мой бот сам по себе имеет в основу *пуллинг*, а я пытаюсь запустить второй параллельно.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно потому что бот уже запущен, используйте другой токен и попробуйте снова

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос